# Bibliography showing as section instead of chapter in scrreprt

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, bibtex, sectioning, chapters

I am trying to add my bibliography to the toc, which works - but instead of showing as a regular chapter, the bib shows as a section.

Since in my understanding, the bib should show as a chapter in report classes, this is confusing me very much. Also, I found many questions on how to reach the opposite (showing as a section instead of a chapter), but nothing on this problem. So maybe it's just a very stupid mistake I made. Anyway, here is my (simplified) latex code test.tex:

```
\documentclass[
  headsepline,
  listof=totoc,% ToC entries for LoF, LoT etc.
  %index=totoc,% uncomment if needed
  bibliography=totoc,% ToC entry for bibliography
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} %this causes the bib to be shown as a section
% encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% font style
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
% citation
\usepackage{apacite}
% german
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

% toc
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\clearpage

% sections
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\shortcite{ESP}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
% lof
\listoffigures
\newpage

% lot
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\newpage

% bib
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Bib file test.bib:

```
@inproceedings{ESP,
    author = {von Ahn, Luis and Dabbish, Laura},
    title = {{Labeling Images with a Computer Game}},
    booktitle = {{Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems}},
    series = {CHI '04},
    year = {2004},
    isbn = {1-58113-702-8},
    location = {Vienna, Austria},
    pages = {319--326},
    numpages = {8},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/985692.985733},
    doi = {10.1145/985692.985733},
    acmid = {985733},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
    keywords = {World Wide Web, distributed knowledge acquisition, image labeling, online games}
}
```

The result is the following:
[image: Bibliography not showing as expected]

As you can see, the bibliography is shown as if it were a section, not a chapter. How can I accomplish that it looks like the lof and lot in the toc?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**   Removed the article option in the document class (which changed nothing) as well as the tocibind package (which resulted in the lof and lot not being shown in the toc, but I guess I can use other commands for that) and added the bib file as well as the content file. 
Loading `hyperref` last as suggested resulted in errors: `!Undefined control sequence.\hyper@@link ...`.

**Edit 2:** The line `\usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}` seems to be causing this behaviour, though I could not find out why. I am searching for a solution now to use scrlayer-scrpage without messing up my bib.

Comment: We do not have your `contents.tex` and  `report.bib`. If I use `\Blinddocument` provided by package `blindtext` and `biblatex-examples.bib`, I can not reproduce the issue. Your global option `article` seems to be unused. Do not use package `tocbibind` with a KOMA-Script class. These classes provide options like `listof=totoc`, `bibliography=totoc`, `index=totoc` to get ToC entries for LoF, LoT, Bibliography and index.

Comment: Welcome! What is the `article` option to the document class supposed to do? Are you sure that doesn't make the bibliography a section?

Comment: Load `hyperref` last.

Comment: @esdd Thank you very much for your help, I updated the question. Removing article option and tocbibind sadly did not change the behaviour.

Comment: @cfr Thank you, too, see the updated question. Loading hyperref last resulted in errors.

Comment: When I try to compile your code, I get the error `No \title given`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know `apacite` was on the 'exception list' and is one of few packages which needs loading after `hyperref`. `apacite` must also be loaded after `babel`.

Comment: Like esdd below, I can't reproduce the result you show with the code you've given. I think you might be better using the book-alike KOMA class so you have access to `\frontmatter` and `\backmatter`, just switching to single-sided if you don't want the double-sided effect. This would save the manual insertion of all the new pages and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combination of the packages `scrlayer-scrpage` and `apacite` does not seem to work. I fixed it by switching from apacite to biblatex apa style.

This works now:

```
\documentclass[
  headsepline,
  listof=totoc,% ToC entries for LoF, LoT etc.
  %index=totoc,% uncomment if needed
  bibliography=totoc,% ToC entry for bibliography
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
% encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% font style
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
% citation
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

% toc
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\clearpage

% sections
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\cite{ESP}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
% lof
\listoffigures
\newpage

% lot
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\newpage

% bib
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is too long for a comment. Using your added bib file and the content.tex I still can not reporduce the issue:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{report.bib}
@inproceedings{ESP,
    author = {von Ahn, Luis and Dabbish, Laura},
    title = {{Labeling Images with a Computer Game}},
    booktitle = {{Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems}},
    series = {CHI '04},
    year = {2004},
    isbn = {1-58113-702-8},
    location = {Vienna, Austria},
    pages = {319--326},
    numpages = {8},
    url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/985692.985733},
    doi = {10.1145/985692.985733},
    acmid = {985733},
    publisher = {ACM},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
    keywords = {World Wide Web, distributed knowledge acquisition, image labeling, online games}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{content.tex}
Test \shortcite{ESP}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[
  headsepline,
  listof=totoc,% ToC entries for LoF, LoT etc.
  %index=totoc,% uncomment if needed
  bibliography=totoc,% ToC entry for bibliography
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
% citation
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\title{Titel}
\author{Autor}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Test \shortcite{ESP}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\bibliography{report}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me, too. There must be something in my code that differs from yours and makes the bib look weird in the toc. I updated the example in the code, showing more of my code.

Comment: Found out it's the srclayer-scrpage package that causes the behaviour. Cannot find out what to change, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because of `scrlayer-scrpage`.

The default option of `apacite` shows the bib as section not as chapter.

To show it as chapter you just have to add the option `nosectionbib` to `apacite` pachage like this:

```
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
```

**Edit:**
Here the complete document:

```
\documentclass[
headsepline,
listof=totoc,% ToC entries for LoF, LoT etc.
%index=totoc,% uncomment if needed
bibliography=totoc,% ToC entry for bibliography
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% font style
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

% citation
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}

% german
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

% toc
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\clearpage

% sections
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\cite{ESP}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

% lof
\listoffigures
\newpage

% lot
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\newpage

% bib
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! This sounds very plausible.  Can you put together a complete document showing this working.